# Removing Element from String Template

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript string called `_categoryItemDivTemplate` that defines HTML markup, including a `<div>` with `class="MakeTopLevelCategory"`.

I thought I can remove that `<div>` with the following code:

```
item = $(_categoryItemDivTemplate);
if (!isTopLevel)
    item.remove('div.MakeTopLevelCategory');
```

But it has no effect.

Am I missing something? Is it necessary to first add the item to the DOM?

**EDIT:**

Here's the template from the code:

```
var _categoryItemDivTemplate =
    '<div class="CategoryItem" style="clear:both;">'
    + '<div class="CategoryHeader">'
    + '<img src="/images/plus.gif" class="Icon"/>'
    + '<img src="/images/icn_folder.gif" class="Icon"/>'
    + '<span class="Title">&nbsp;</span>'
    + '<div style="float:right; font-size: 11px;" class="CategorySelector">'
        + '<div class="DeleteCategory" title="Delete this Category">&nbsp;</div>'
        + '<div class="EditCategory" title="Rename this Category">&nbsp;</div>'
        + '<div class="MakeTopLevelCategory" title="Make this Category a Top-level Category">&nbsp</div>'
        + '<div class="MoveSubcategory" title="Move this Category">&nbsp;</div>'
        + '<div class="SubcategoryMarker AddSubcategory" title="Add a new Subcategory to this Category">&nbsp;</div>'
        + '<div class="PackageCostingMarker AddPackage" title="Add a new Package to this Category">&nbsp;</div>'
        + '<div class="ProductCostingMarker AddProduct" title="Add a new Product to this Category">&nbsp;</div>'
        + '<div class="NarrativeMarker AddArticle" title="Add a new Article to this Category">&nbsp;</div>'
    + '</div>'
    + '</div>'
    + '<div class="CategoryItems" style="display: none;">'
    + '</div>'
    + '</div>';
```

Comment: For people wanting to test with code `_categoryItemDivTemplate = '<span><div class="makeTopLevelCategory"><span></span></div></span>'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing it from the object does not removes it from the string, if you want to remove it from the string then you need to replace the string with the object sources so try

```
item = $('<div />', {html:'_categoryItemDivTemplate'});
if (!isTopLevel) {
    item.find('div.MakeTopLevelCategory').remove();
}
```

Comment: When I try this (with _String_ I put in comment on question) it's still included

Comment: @JonathanWood then it should work, can you share the template

Comment: @JonathanWood the syntax was entirely messed up - you need to find the object and then remove it

Comment: Yes, it appears `find()` was necessary. I'm surprised. The whole point of jQuery is to query markup. I don't understand why `find()` is needed here.